# Delete duplicate records and keep earliest only if the records are less than 2min different

Tags: sql, duplicates, azure-sql-database

I am working on an Azure SQL database (T-SQL) where I have a table looking like this :

```
Device | MsgDate (type datetime2) | MsgType | Latitude | Longitude | other irrelevant columns
-------+---------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------------
1500   |  25/10/2020 14:01:05      |    1    |   40.5   |    -72.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 14:01:45      |    1    |   40.5   |    -72.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 14:31:23      |    2    |   40.6   |    -74.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 15:02:14      |    2    |   43.5   |    -78.3  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 15:24:55      |    3    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 15:25:03      |    3    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 18:36:31      |    1    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
1501   |  25/10/2020 15:17:44      |    1    |   39.5   |    -78.2  |  ...
1501   |  25/10/2020 15:18:21      |    1    |   39.5   |    -78.2  |  ...
1501   |  25/10/2020 15:39:02      |    3    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
```

I am trying to deduplicate this table based on the following rule :

- each DeviceID/MsgDate/MsgType tuple is a product key, but MsgDate that are less than 2min different from each other are actually identical and therefore duplicates for a single device and a single message type.
  In case of duplicates, I am keeping the first message (but it does not really matter, as long as only one message is kept).

For the moment, I only focus on messages that are of type 1 and 3.

The table I am therefore trying to get is :

```
Device |  MsgDate (type datetime2) | MsgType | Latitude | Longitude | other irrelevant columns
-------+---------------------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------------------
1500   |  25/10/2020 14:01:05      |    1    |   40.5   |    -72.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 14:31:23      |    2    |   40.6   |    -74.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 15:02:14      |    2    |   43.5   |    -78.3  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 15:24:55      |    3    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
1500   |  25/10/2020 18:36:31      |    1    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
1501   |  25/10/2020 15:17:44      |    1    |   39.5   |    -78.2  |  ...
1501   |  25/10/2020 15:39:02      |    3    |   48.5   |    -12.5  |  ...
```

I have tried the following method, but unfortunately is only truncates the minutes from the datetime part, so it does not handles correctly duplicates datetimes for which the minute has changed (such as 24:55 -> 25:03).

```
SELECT      POS1.DeviceID,
            POS1.MsgDate,
            POS1.MessageType,
            POS1.Latitude,
            POS1.Longitude
    FROM PositionTable POS1
    --WHERE MsgType = '1' or MsgType = '3'
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  DeviceID,
                    MIN(MsgDate) AS UniqueMsgDate
            FROM PositionTable
            WHERE MsgType = '1' OR MsgType = '3'
            GROUP BY DeviceID,
            DATEPART(YEAR, MsgDate),
            DATEPART(MONTH, MsgDate),
            DATEPART(DAY, MsgDate),
            DATEPART(HOUR, MsgDate),
            (DATEPART(MINUTE, MsgDate) / 2)
            ) POS2
            ON POS1.DeviceID = POS2.DeviceID AND POS1.MsgDate = POS2.UniqueMsgDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `lag()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             lag(msgdate) over (partition by device order by msgdate) as prev_msgdate
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where msgdate < dateadd(minute, 2, prev_msgdate);
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly ! As I am working on a reference table, I just changed the `DELETE FROM` into a `SELECT * FROM todelete WHERE msgdate > dateadd`...